# Sudden Eclipse ClassNotFoundException When running Codename One Simulator

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

Eclipse started failing when running the simultor. This was previously working, we didn't change anything.

```sh
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.MyMainClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:116)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:55)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$3.run(Executor.java:219)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'ProjectName' is missing required library: 'lib/impl/cls' ProjectName Build path Build Path Problem
Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'ProjectName' is missing required library: 'lib/impl/stubs' ProjectName Build path Build Path Problem
```

Eclipse clean project, project refresh and codename one lib refresh did not fix the issue. Neither did the manual deletion of the output folders (build, bin and dist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build path:

- Remove the `imb/impl/cls` and `lib/impl/stubs` entries (see the image below)
- Apply and refresh the project
- Go back and add those libs again apply and the project should be fine now

[image]